# While installing wordpress getting error: Can’t select database

Tags: php, wordpress

We were able to connect to the database server (which means your username and password is okay) but not able to select the `learningWordPress` database.

Comment: Have you created the database (which name)?

Comment: I dont think i have ever seen a more helpful error message - did you read it and follow its suggestions?

Comment: I created database name with  "learningWordPress "

Comment: @Kiran, I guess if you got the answer, then let users know so that they do not waste their time in answering/searching your question

Comment: @Kiran, If you've got the answer, then please post your answer so that other people in the same situation would be helped.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Try to connect on this database using a simple php file. 
* This step is to see if something is wrong with PHP or Database
2 - Try to create other database, without the "Wordpress" in the name
* If you find some problem on this step, probably Wordpress dosen´t allow this word in database name
3 - Try to delete and create again the database with the same name